# How to search similar sites with Google?

Tags: google-search

One addition to Firefox provides button to search similar sites with Google, **not pages**. I've forgotten its name and I can't look at its query.

So how can I search similar sites with Google?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the **related:** operator.

For example:

[related:google.com](http://www.google.com.tr/search?q=related%3agoogle.com)

Comment: As of October 2019, the "related" command always returns an empty list.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome has an extension called [Google Similar Pages](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-similar-pages/pjnfggphgdjblhfjaphkjhfpiiekbbej).

Its results were equivalent to the "related" command.